# OMNeT++ 5.1 FATAL: opplibs.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: omnet++

I just downloaded and compiled the new release of OMNeT++ 5.1 on Windows 10. I had no problem building it. I checked to see if I could run the dyna project and that worked perfectly. The issues came in with my project. I was trying to import a project (using "Import Existing Project Into Workspace") that I had been working on in 5.0 and I received this error message:

[FATAL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXay6.png)

I was able to work around it (for a little bit) by creating a new project and copying all of the files over. I ran into an issue again with my build. It didn't print an error so I tried to run from the command line and got an error with one of my .NED files. I went into Eclipse to open the .NED file and I got this error:

[.NED File Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhylQ.png)

I need some 64-bit stuff so I have to move to 5.1 to do what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second (NED) issue is just a consequence of the first (not being able to  load the native lib at all). Did you start the IDE from the MinGW env command prompt?

Comment: Just tried that and it worked! I tried the shortcut again to check but that still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: You always have to start the IDE from the provided command line windows. The reason is: OMNeT++ does not want to modify any system wide variables (i.e. PATH) to allow installing and running several different versions of OMNeT++ on the same machine. That command line window sets various environment variables and the PATH which contains the OMNeT++ toolchain. Without that, OMNeT++ is non-functional.